# is there a way to check if the file was processed by autoloader already?

Tags: azure-databricks, autoload

I upload files to data bricks file system every two day, i want to know if there's a place or log to see if some file is processed or not?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you provide the code what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link:https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/production.html#querying-files-discovered-by-auto-loader

For python code refer this link:[Get the list of loaded files from Databricks Autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244618/get-the-list-of-loaded-files-from-databricks-autoloader)

sample code `SELECT * FROM cloud_files_state('path/to/checkpoint');`

Comment: Hi @Sharma, do you know why i will got error 'could not resolve `CLOUD_FILES_STATE` to a table-valued function; line 1 pos 17' after running the sql? I run the sql in a notebook.

Comment: Can you please send the code which you ran

Comment: this the sql. SELECT * FROM CLOUD_FILES_STATE('/FileStore/test/checkpoint/web');

Comment: No idea, even i was trying to recreate but i was not able to do that.

Comment: it works fine if your checkpoint is in storage, e.g.

`select * from CLOUD_FILES_STATE('abfss://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mytable/_checkpoint_folder')`